# I need help in redirecting URLs in Kentico v6.0.58

Tags: redirect, kentico

I need to move contents from a file in Kentico into a new post/article...I am new to Kentico by the way. I already created new posts for those files and I want to redirect the old file link to the new post I created. I have tried the alias thing but it doesn't seem to work. Would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Geneva, you need to navigate page Properties -> Menu section and set URL Redirection field.

More details [here](https://devnet.kentico.com/docs/6_0/devguide/index.html?document_properties_menu.htm).